Honeywell Gas Control Valve Gas Smell
There was a gas smell coming from my Honeywell Gas Control Valve and I called the gas company out. They had a tool that they used SENSIT GOLD G2 that they used to check for gas leaks. On it, the highest reading they got said .9, this was between the pilot tube and the manifold tube. The employee from the gas company was very young. They said that these readings should be 0. There were no bubbles from their soap test. They didn't turn off the gas to the house, just turned it off to the water heater.
I just want to understand what the .9 number means.
I have seen many posts on Reddit about these gas control valves where they get replaced and they still smell gas.


Gas smell, plus spark, equals boom.  You want 0 reading, no gas smell.

Why didn't you ask the employee from the gas company what the .9 reading means?

what does the instruction manual says


I just want to understand what the .9 number means.

The answer is a bit complex, and it is worth noting that it is not unusual to find that persons (even professionals and emergency responders) using combustible gas detectors have not been adequately trained to clearly understand how they work and/or how to properly interpret their readings.
That detector can be configured several ways. I would have used it in PPM (parts per million) mode, but the listed resolution in that mode (1PPM or 10PPM) means that you would never get a ".9" reading. This means it must have been set for "LEL" (lower explosive limit) mode or "% Gas" mode.
This means that, assuming LEL mode, your gas concentration was detected at nine-tenths of 1% of the fuel-air mixture needed for ignition. Assuming the gas is methane, and the detector is calibrated to methane (it can also be calibrated to propane...), the concentration at that time and place was way too lean to ignite (the LEL for methane is around 5% in air).
If the detector was in "% Gas" mode, the reading was nine-tenths of 1% concentration in air; again, too lean to ignite.
If you look at the machine's accuracy/error margin of 10% (for LEL) and 5% (for %Gas), the actual concentration could have been higher (or lower...) In the end, zero is the number you want and the fact that you have smelled gas and that the machine is giving a response at all means there is likely a leak.
So, regardless of the user's level of understanding, the detector and user did their jobs.


Agreed, but still...

In my uninformed opinion, that number still means "leak confirmed, not critical yet but can accumulate, can get worse, get it fixed." A properly functioning has appliance should never leak enough that you can persistently smell the tracer. (Methane itself is odorless;other gass s like hydrogen sulfide are added so you will notice leaks.)
The gas company can test and confirm, but won't fix anything that isn't their equipment; call your service tech. If you're renting, call your landlord and ask them to call the service tech, or ask if they'll reimburse if you do so. (Some owners appreciate having renters handle it so they don't have to be on site.)

In my area the gas company will sometimes make small repairs to appliances for free, to keep the gas (and $$) flowing...

Ah. Makes sense, retaining customers and maintaining  reputation; a leak would be serious bad press, after all. On the other hand, it sounds like this kid wasn't the one you'd want attempting the repair... Call back and ask them if they'd send someone to repair it?
